# How match format between two numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this numbers

```
const number1 = 123.45
const number2 = 1249.4
const number3 = 111.20
const number4 = 12.10
```

i want achieve something like this

```
number1 == number3 : true
number1 == number2 : false
number1 == number4 : false
```

So what i want to do is matching the number format.

I can simply split it, but how can i achieve it in regex ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is easy with string inputs, but I think impossible as described with numeric input.  `number3` and `number4` get parsed as 111.2 and 12.1 before any code gets executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a RegEx to get each part of the numbers, and then count their length. We can consider:

- How many characrters before the decimal;
- If there is a decimal at all;
- How many characters after the decimal.

The following RegEx can do the trick:

```
/^(\d)+(\.\d+)?$/
```

The key part here is that wrapping each of the parts in brackets creates "capture groups", from which we can extract the matching text, e.g. the part before the decimal, and the part after.

From here, we can run the RegEx against both numbers, and then check their corresponding capture group lengths:

```
function numberFormat(a, b) {
    const getParts = /^(\d)+(\.\d+)?$/
    let one = (a + "").match(getParts);
    let two = (b + "").match(getParts);
    return one[1].length == two[1] && one[2].length == two[2].length;
}
```

It's worth noting that the `0`th item in the result arrays is always the full matching string, and then each additional item corresponds to one of the capture groups.

---

This won't quite work for your exact example as-is though. Javascript discards any redundant digits **when you create them**, so e.g. `111.20` becomes `111.2` at the time of its definition, and as such there's no way for us to get that `0` back. Likewise, something like `7.00` just becomes `7`.

The best way to solve this problem obviously depends on your use case. One way could be to store the numbers as strings and then `parseInt` them as needed, however there may be better options available depending on what's actually happening in the rest of your program --- e.g. if you're taking these numbers in from the user only to run them through this function, they don't *actually* need to ever be numbers, etc.